# How do I stop Outlook from changing its icon in the taskbar?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, taskbar

Outlook changes its icon in the taskbar when I select a different item in the folder pane (Inbox, Deleted) or a different section (Calendar, To-Do List). It seems like this just happened with a recent update. I want the usual Outlook icon so I can recognize it immediately.

For instance:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm running Outlook 2016 on Windows 10, with taskbar buttons combined only when full (I'm not interested in always combining my buttons as a solution, though it does work). Thank you.

Comment: This has always happened in every version of Outlook I have used.

Comment: What is the full version number of Outlook at you using? See example here: http://imgur.com/download/tt6Fxtc

Comment: @Ramhound Ha, maybe I just never noticed until now. My setup keeps Outlook as my last icon in the row and I guess I've been reliant on that

Comment: @thilinaR 16.0.4432.1000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way it works. If you close all Outlook windows and then open Outlook from scratch (and have only this first Outlook Window open) and then simply click on any folder in the folder pane on the left, the icon on the task bar doesn't change.

This is how it would be if you did this:

[image: Outlook Main Window]

**However**, you can right-click any folder in the folder pane on the left, and click `Open in New Window`. If you do this, the icon of the new (2nd) window on the task bar changes based on which folder you are on.

This is what the icon on the task bar would look like for any new windows opened as described:

[image: Outlook non-main Window]

**Note:** When you open this second window as described above, you can close the first (or initial) Outlook window that opened and you can still continue using Outlook.

If you just updated your system, you might also want to restart and try these steps to make sure it works as described.